# making api calls on facebook login demo code

Tags: php, facebook

i've started dabbling with the facebook login demo code and i was just wondering how to extract individual information from my code such as display pic, name, first-name, last-name, username and henceforth.

currently the demo shows this:

```
Your User Object (/me)

    Array
    (
        [id] => 647445630
        [name] => John Molanza
        [first_name] => John
        [last_name] => Molanza
        [link] => http://www.facebook.com/johnmolanza
        [username] => johnmolanza
        [gender] => male
        [timezone] => 1
        [locale] => en_GB
        [verified] => 1
        [updated_time] => 2011-05-24T03:12:09+0000
    )
```

alongside my display picture and other things. but how do you display each piece of information individually for example [last_name] or [first_name] instead of everything at once.

here is the code i am using below - thanking you in advance!

> ```
> //config
> include "resources/Connections/kite.php";
>
> require 'resources/facebook/src/facebook.php';
>
> $facebook = new Facebook(array(
>   'appId'  => $appid_kite,
>   'secret' => $secret_kite,
> ));
>
> // Get User ID
> $user = $facebook->getUser();
>
> // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is
> ```
>
> logged in.
>       //
>       // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
>       // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
>       // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.
>
> ```
> if ($user) {
>   try {
>     // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
>     $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
>   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
>     error_log($e);
>     $user = null;
>   }
> }
>
> // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user
> ```
>
> state.
>       if ($user) {
>         $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
>       } else {
>         $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
>       }
>       // This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
>       $naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');
>
> ```
> ?>
> <!doctype html>
> <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
>   <head>
>     <title>php-sdk</title>
>     <style>
>       body {
>         font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
>       }
>       h1 a {
>         text-decoration: none;
>         color: #3b5998;
>       }
>       h1 a:hover {
>         text-decoration: underline;
>       }
>     </style>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <h1>php-sdk</h1>
>
>     <?php if ($user): ?>
>       <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
>     <?php else: ?>
>       <div>
>         Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
>         <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
>       </div>
>     <?php endif ?>
>
>     <h3>PHP Session</h3>
>     <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>
>
>     <?php if ($user): ?>
>       <h3>You</h3>
>       <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php
> ```
>
> echo $user; ?>/picture">
>
> ```
>       <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
>       <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
>     <?php else: ?>
>       <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
>     <?php endif ?>
>
>     <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
>     <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
>     <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: see this:)http://www.9lessons.info/2011/01/facebook-graph-api-connect-with-php-and.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the array, so you can get each value by key. Try this instead of print_r($user_profile)

```
echo $user_profile['first_name']; //Prints John Molanza
echo '<a href="'.$user_profile['link'].'">Go to my profile</a>';
```